# Why aren't description lists formatted on Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, markdown

[Description lists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl), formerly known as definition lists, are a form of HTML markup. While they are not a part of [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), they may be created on Stack Exchange through [inline HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/380598). However, they are not displayed in any helpful way, for example.

```
<dl>
<dt>Word 1</dt><dd>Definition 1</dd>
<dt>Word 2</dt><dd>Definition 2</dd>
<dt>Word 3</dt><dd>Definition 3</dd>
</dl>

Paragraph after description list. Notice the lack of spacing.
```

is presented as:

Word 1

Definition 1

Word 2

Definition 2

Word 3

Definition 3

Paragraph after description list. Notice the lack of spacing.

The default styling for `<dd>` is `margin-inline-start: 40px` in [HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#lists), and I believe that has been [widely implemented](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp) in [various browsers and standards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22510220/5389585) for some time, yet this default is overwritten on Stack Exchange. **Can at least the default indentation be restored?** I would be happy if `<dt>` was bolded as well, and `<dd>` had `margin-bottom: .8em`.

Comment: Related: [Better style for HTML 'definition list' <dl> elements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22972/241919) (actually a duplicate, but since this question got [status-review] tag instead...)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We're doing some active work around this and will update here when there's more.

Comment: This should be updated with https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting

Comment: *cough* You should post an answer :D

Comment: And you should @ mention @JourneymanGeek

Comment: Hmph.. fine @JonChan ^ see above comment 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting)

Comment: @zcoop98: The spacing issue on a paragraph following a description list has been fixed, and bolding on `<dd>` is active. I wish I had done a screenshot so others could appreciate the change before and after. However, still no `margin-inline-start` to indent `<dt>`.